# How to resolve a multisampled depth buffer to a depth texture?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, depth-buffer, render-to-texture, multisampling

I'm having trouble with the msaa depth buffer resolving to a depth texture. I create my glTexImage2d for both my color texture and my depth texture and bind them to the "resolve" ( non-msaa ) framebuffer. Then I create and bind another framebuffer and create my multisampled renderbuffers ( both color and depth ). I know to get my color texture information from the multisampled renderbuffer I just blit with the write buffer being my color texture framebuffer and the read buffer being my msaa-framebuffer. My question is how do I blit my multisampled depth buffer to my depth texture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do this the same way you would do for the color buffer, only you would use `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` and make sure you use `GL_NEAREST` for the filter mode. If you want linear filtering on a depth/stencil buffer, for whatever reason, you can actually do this in GLSL if you use a depth texture (of course this still remains invalid for MSAA textures) - but it is invalid to do this using `glBlitFramebuffer (...)`.

You do not have to do any of the `glReadBuffer (...)` nonsense like you do when you want to select an individual color buffer, `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` will copy the depth buffer from the bound `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` to the bound `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`.

Comment: So if I'm blitting the color buffer like... glDrawBuffer( GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 ); glReadBuffer( GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 ); glBlitFrameBuffer( 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFERBIT, GL_NEAREST );...can I just add the depth buffer bit to the BlitFrameBuffer like so... glBlitFrameBuffer( 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFERBIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST );...and gl will figure it out?

Comment: That _should_ work. Provided your read and draw framebuffers both have  a color attachment 0 and a depth buffer. Things might get hairy if you have a color buffer and depth buffer that have differing dimensions (yes, this is possible) or if your depth buffer is a packed depth/stencil (as is usually the case if you want to blit directly to the window).

Comment: I should add to this that MSAA depth textures are a Shader Model 4.1 feature (that is to say, they were not ***required*** until SM 4.1). They are not supported on a lot of hardware older than AMD Radeon HD 3xxx or GeForce 2xx. In theory, this should only affect you if you were going the opposite direction - trying to blit from an MSAA depth texture to a single-sampled renderbuffer/texture, but you never know.

Comment: Let me know what hardware you are using, I am curious to know if this is the culprit; I have my own theories.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry it took so long. That worked. For some reason I was just really twisted by whether or not I needed to set glReadBuffer and glDrawBuffer to the GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and then blit it. I appreciate you getting back to me so fast.

Comment: That worked for me too! I got (resolved) color texture anti-aliased, but depth texture aliased. What's the problem? I use Intel HD3000 GPU.